# How to send a value to a Bluetooth module from an app using an alarm trigger?

Tags: java, android

I am quite proficient with programming in general but new to android. I am trying to send a string to a Bluetooth module from the app with an alarm trigger. I am able to send this string with click event but when the same function is invoked with an alarm trigger the Bluetooth module receives the null string. I believe the problem occurs when the value is getting written when the alarm is triggered. Any ideas to solve the problem will be appreciated.  Please let me know if the framing of the problem is not clear as I am still new I am not familiar with the jargons.

```
public static final String TAG = "MyAPP";
        private static final int UART_PROFILE_CONNECTED = 20;
        private static final int UART_PROFILE_DISCONNECTED = 21;
        private int mState = UART_PROFILE_DISCONNECTED;
        UartService mService = new UartService();
        TimePicker timePicker;
        public Button s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;

        public Data1()
        { 
            sample();
        }

            private void sample() {

                Log.e(TAG, "Working");

                String value = "5";
                //send data to service
    //                    value = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
                Log.d(TAG, "ByteValue(Data5) = " + value);
                UartService mService = new UartService();
                mService.WritetoTimer(value);

            }

            @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(activity_main2);
            service_init();
            s1=findViewById(R.id.Data1);
            s2=findViewById(R.id.Data2);
            s3=findViewById(R.id.Data3);
            s4=findViewById(R.id.Data4);
            s5=findViewById(R.id.Data5);
            s5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String message = "5";
                    byte[] value;
                    try {

                        //send data to service
                        value = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
                        Log.d(TAG, "ByteValue(Data5) = " + value);
                        mService.writeRXCharacteristic(value);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        //UART service connected/disconnected
            public ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder rawBinder) {
                UartService mService = new UartService();
                mService = ((UartService.LocalBinder) rawBinder).getService();
                Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected mService= " + mService);
                if (!mService.initialize()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
                    finish();
                }
            }
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName classname) {
                UartService mService = new UartService();
                mService = null;
                }
            };
        @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
            private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                //Handler events that received from UART service
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    }
                };
            public final BroadcastReceiver UARTStatusChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                assert action != null;
                if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED)) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "UART_CONNECT_MSG");
                            mState = UART_PROFILE_CONNECTED;
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED)) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "UART_DISCONNECT_MSG");
                            mState = UART_PROFILE_DISCONNECTED;
                            mService.close();
                            }
                    });
                }
                //*********************//
                if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED)) {
                    mService.enableTXNotification();
                }
                //*********************//
                if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE)) {
                    final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(UartService.EXTRA_DATA);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                String text = new String(txValue, "UTF-8");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                //*********************//
                if (action.equals(UartService.DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART)) {
                    showMessage("Device doesn't support UART. Disconnecting");
                    mService.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            };
            public void service_init() {
                Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this, UartService.class);
                bindService(bindIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(UARTStatusChangeReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
            }
            public static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
                final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                intentFilter.addAction(UartService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
                intentFilter.addAction(UartService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
                intentFilter.addAction(UartService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
                intentFilter.addAction(UartService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
                intentFilter.addAction(UartService.DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
                return intentFilter;
            }
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                service_init();
                super.onStart();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
            Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");
            try {
              LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(UARTStatusChangeReceiver);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
              Log.e(TAG, ignore.toString());
            }
```